# Data filtering from longtext field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a table where there are 3 entity `id(type varchar)`, `name(type varchar)` and `menu(type longtext)`. In the `menu` I have put some `longtxt` values, e.g

[image]

Now I want to get the id's or the names where the `name`=any one of the long text vales. I have tried, but simply it didn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`name`, `menu`);
```

Comment: Thank you Ben for your valuable reply...by the way i have tried the query like this: SELECT id FROM filter WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`VEG`,menu). But it did end with an error code said: #1054 - Unknown column 'VEG' in 'where clause'.....

Comment: @LMunna You have to escape your strings: `SELECT id FROM filter WHERE FIND_IN_SET("VEG",menu)`

Comment: Ya ya Yes ...me and my bad eyes..thanks a lot finally it seems like this: SELECT id FROM filter WHERE FIND_IN_SET("VEG",menu) and the result is id R2 R3